# UIView transitionWithView animating property change: slide in from right?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, uitextview

I have a readonly UITextView, and I'm updating the text.
When the new text appears, I want it to animate as follows: New text slides in from the right, as the old text slides offscreen toward the left side.

Is it possible to do this with transitionWithView? If not, what's the best way to do it? I can make it do a CrossDissolve, but that's not the animation I'm looking for:

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.storyTextView
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    [self.storyTextView setText:withStory.storyText];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

The reason for insisting on the right to left animation is because eventually I want the user to be able to trigger it by swiping toward the left on the UITextView.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`CATransition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) will allow you to do this, with a transition type of 'push' and a subtype of 'from right'. It's very straightforward to use:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition new];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

// Make any view changes
self.textView.text = newText;

// Add the transition
[self.textView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
```

Note that this, while it's what you've asked for, won't fit nicely with a gesture without some extra tinkering - to tie it to a gesture you'd need to do something like set the layer speed to 0 and the manually update the progress of the animation to match your gesture.

Comment: @jrturton If I use this on a cell's imageView it works perfectly until it gets reused. Then you get the reused cell's old image that transitions to the new image. I always want it to go from blank to image. Without animation all you would to is nil the imageView's image in prepareForReuse, but that isn't enough here to reset it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlexanderofNorway that sounds like a different enough use case to be worth its own question - I'm surprised setting the image to nil doesn't work

Comment: The problem with this solution is it includes a fade.

Comment: Oh hello... just giving this a try now :P

Answer (score 1):

What about just using UIView animateWithDuration and slide the one `textView` to the right while sliding a new `textView` from the left.  Here is an example just have to work out the positions.  Let me know if this is what you were looking to do.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.textView2.frame = CGRectMake(1000.0,self.textView1.frame.origin.y,self.textView2.frame.size.width,self.textView2.frame.size.height);

}
- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.textView1.frame = CGRectMake(-200.0,self.textView1.frame.origin.y,self.textView1.frame.size.width,self.textView1.frame.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.textView2.center = (CGPointMake(200, 200));
        }];
    }];

}
```

Comment: That could work. Using two UITextViews adds complexity I was hoping to avoid, but I will try this one if the others don't work out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this.

You can create a containerView for your text view and then change the coordinates using `UIView` animations to give it a slide from right to left.

Please see code below.

First declare a container view and the make the required text view its subview.

In .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextView *childTextView; //I have set it as subview in xib
```

In .m make sure to set the following in `viewDidLoad` or in Xib

```
self.containerView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Gestures

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recog = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeText)];
recog.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.containerView addGestureRecognizer:recog];
```

Beautification (for this you would need QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h)

```
self.containerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.containerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
```

To the Point

```
- (void)changeText
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^(void){
        CGRect endPos = self.childTextView.frame;
        endPos.origin.x -= endPos.size.width; //Move it out of the view's frame to the left
        self.childTextView.frame = endPos;
    } completion:^(BOOL done){
        CGRect startPos  = self.childTextView.frame;
        startPos.origin.x += (2*startPos.size.width);// this will take it to the right.
        self.childTextView.frame = startPos;
        self.childTextView.text = @"Changed text";

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^(void){
            CGRect displayPos = self.childTextView.frame;
            displayPos.origin.x -= displayPos.size.width; // To compensate for the double +ve on top
            self.childTextView.frame = displayPos;
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I used your gesture recognizer code directly on the UITextView, and implemented @jrturton's CATransition suggestion. It's working nicely although you can't control the animation speed by moving your thumb faster or slower. Thanks.